# How to do "Join" in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I know there is the MapReduce option. However, it is rather painful. Are there any good open source tools which can enable me to use SQL-like queries to hit a MongoDB?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are trying to do a join, you're probably doing it wrong. Either you execute a second query to get related records, or you restructure the data so that the related records are a single record.

Answer (score 1):

The Link [Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/) is a pretty direct SQL mapping for common queries that is quite useful and hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks sweetiewill! Is there a link so I can review the SQL mapping?

Comment: I have embedded the link above just now